# Angular Firebase ngFor returning [object object]

Tags: angular, firebase, ngfor

Database

```
"testTree" : {
"-L7SdD-wGoFfewfde2oI" : { //Firebase key
  "testX" : {
    "ef43E2Vde" : { // User Generated
      "testY" : {
        "numX" : 87,
      }
    },
    "Me5Eq2V9e" : { // User Generated
      "testY" : {
        "numX": 12
      }
    }
  },
  "treeName" : "TestTREE",
},
"-L7heD-VdO9efgDaIOp" : {
  "testX" : {
    "9vEf029QP" : {
      "testY" : {
        "numX" : 35,
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Function:

```
treeData: any[] = [];

getTree() {
this.db.list('/testTree/')
.valueChanges()
.subscribe(res => {
    Object.keys(res)
    .map(key => {
      this.treeData.push(res[key]);
      console.log(res[key]);
    })
})
```

}

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor='let userData of treeData'>
{{ userData.devices }} //typo
{{ userData.testX }}
```

Output:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]  
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

From my understand *ngFor will only iterate over array but not object.  I thought that I am storing and pushing the result to my array treeData.  I just want to be able to output all 'numX'.  What am I doing wrong?  Will it even be possible to iterate my database with the "User Generated" to reach 'numX'?

Comment: you can put {{ userData.devices | json}} to see the structure of the item in the for, I think the problem can be in the map

Comment: {{userData.devices | json }} is a typo but when I put {{ userData.testX | json }} I get { "ef43E2Vde": { "testY": { "numX": 87, ...} which contains all the data it suppose to.   userData.testX.val() gives me ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.testX.val is not a function

Answer (score 0):

So if you know how to get  `{"ef43E2Vde": { "testY": { "numX": 87, ...}`, as you mentionned in your comment, you just have to "treat" this javaScript object in order to get the data you need.

For example if you do `Object.keys(userData.testX)[0]` you will get "ef43E2Vde"

More precisely you could use the following function

```
function getAttributeByIndex(obj, index){
  var i = 0;
  for (var attr in obj){
    if (index === i){
      return obj[attr];
    }
    i++;
  }
  return null;
}
```

and call `getAttributeByIndex(userData.testX, 0)` which will return the { "numX": 87, ...} object

Answer (score 0):

You can try with snapshotChanges() instead of valueChanges() also you can get the id too in the same json:

```
getTree() {
return this.db.collection('testTree').snapshotChanges().map(
    spapDoc => {
      return spapDoc.map(doc => {
        return {
          id: doc.payload.doc.id,
          ...doc.payload.doc.data()
        };
      });
    });
}
```